# PayPal recurring payments using C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, asp.net-mvc-5

I'll shorten my question as much as possible.

I would like to know if there is a way for me to avoid to force user to enter his/her credit card number with rest of the CC informations ON MY WEBSITE...???

The PayPal API documentation that I'm currently reading:

```
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/recurring-payments/
```

So basically what it says is:

```
Include all required credit card information in the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile request.
```

And one of the parameters that I would send out from my website are:

```
1. Card type
2. Card number
3. Card expiration date
4. CVV2
```

And so on...

This is utterly unacceptable for me because my website doesn't uses the HTTPS protocol and the data traveling from my website to PayPal would be unsafe...

Is their API really this dumb that I can't do a simple recurring payment without sending all this data to them???

Are there any workaround to this ???

Comment: Problem is without SSL and HTTPS this violates PCI standards. So answer is NO you can not collect credit card information to pass on to Providers without it being secure. As your application would need to collect the information, send to provider and then receive a token back, so the next time your application can just use the token to ask for payment. Best bet is just use the standard PayPal with a redirect to your site.

Comment: @VDWWD your duplicate link is not available.

Comment: @Liakat, it seems the question was deleted. Sorry about that.